Validity of an inductive step for a problem of probability
Consider the next problem
Problem. Let $A_1,...,A_n$ be events. We assume that at least one event occurs, but never more than three. We also assume that the probability of having at least two events is $1/2$. If $P(A_i)=p$, $P(A_i\cap A_j)=q$ for $i\neq j$ and $P(A_i\cap A_j\cap A_j)=r$ for $i<j<k$, then $p\geq 3/(2n)$ and $q\leq 4/n$.
I want to do a proof by induction on $n$, I have proved the basis case, but I have problems with the inductive step and think I have found a solution. I divide the inductive step into two cases. The first case is when the event $A_{n+1}$ doesn't occur and the second is when it does. My question is if this division is valid, for instance
If $A_{n+1}$ doesn't occur, then we can apply the inductive hypothesis to $A_1,...,A_n$ and we get $p\geq 3/(2n)\geq 3/2(n+1)$
In the second case, we define $B_i=A_i\cap A_{n+1}$ and apply the inductive hypothesis to $B_1,...,B_n$. Of course, at least one event occurs for $B_1,...,B_n$, and, since $A_{n+1}$ occurs, the probability of having two events is also $1/2$.

I do not quite understand induction or the final paragraph.  If you have an extra event $A_{n+1}$ then you cannot say at least one of $A_1,\ldots,A_n$ occurs so the inductive hypothesis no longer applies at that level.  Not do I see where the $1/2$ appears.

I am surprised that you have not used inclusion-exclusion and ${n \choose 1}p-{n \choose 2}q+{n \choose 3}r=1$

@Henry, because then we have $1/2=\binom{n}{2}q-something$ and I don't know how to handle that something. I have seen some posts here with that approach, but I can't understand

Dividing into cases while verifying the inductive step is perfectly fine, and your solution is valid.
Logically, what you do is to show that a statement is true, so it is fine for you to do it through casework, and show that is holds true under any of those cases.
